# Got the error org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException while starting jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I tryed to start jenkins but got the error "org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/run/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.413.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:130:53:  java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Answer (score 1):

You can try downgrading jenkins so it can start and then going into plugins and installing updates, especially for maven.

Comment: Solved it by removing plugins. And then reinstalling them...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error earlier today after a migration from Hudson 1.339 or something like that to Jenkins 1.413

In fact, the problem is caused by incompatibility of plugins. I deleted the `/var/lib/hudson` folder which contained my workspace and thus all the projets, plugins settings.

After that, I reinstalled Jenkins and it worked perfectly.
Hope that helps! I've lost a couple of hours with that...